# Cannot get kube-dns to start on Kubernetes

Tags: dns, kubernetes, coreos

Hoping someone can help.
I have a 3x node CoreOS cluster running Kubernetes. The nodes are as follows:
192.168.1.201 - Controller
192.168.1.202 - Worker Node
192.168.1.203 - Worker Node

The cluster is up and running, and I can run the following commands:

```
> kubectl get nodes

NAME            STATUS                     AGE
192.168.1.201   Ready,SchedulingDisabled   1d
192.168.1.202   Ready                      21h
192.168.1.203   Ready                      21h

> kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system

NAME                                    READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-apiserver-192.168.1.201            1/1       Running            2          1d
kube-controller-manager-192.168.1.201   1/1       Running            4          1d
kube-dns-v20-h4w7m                      2/3       CrashLoopBackOff   15         23m
kube-proxy-192.168.1.201                1/1       Running            2          1d
kube-proxy-192.168.1.202                1/1       Running            1          21h
kube-proxy-192.168.1.203                1/1       Running            1          21h
kube-scheduler-192.168.1.201            1/1       Running            4          1d
```

As you can see, the kube-dns service is not running correctly. It keeps restarting and I am struggling to understand why. Any help in debugging this would be greatly appreciated (or pointers at where to read about debugging this. Running kubectl logs does not bring anything back...not sure if the addons function differently to standard pods.

Running a kubectl describe pods, I can see the containers are killed due to being unhealthy:

```
16m           16m             1       {kubelet 192.168.1.203} spec.containers{kubedns}        Normal          Created         Created container with docker id 189afaa1eb0d; Security:[seccomp=unconfined]
16m           16m             1       {kubelet 192.168.1.203} spec.containers{kubedns}        Normal          Started         Started container with docker id 189afaa1eb0d
14m           14m             1       {kubelet 192.168.1.203} spec.containers{kubedns}        Normal          Killing         Killing container with docker id 189afaa1eb0d: pod "kube-dns-v20-h4w7m_kube-system(3a545c95-ea19-11e6-aa7c-52540021bfab)" container "kubedns" is unhealthy, it will be killed and re-created
```

Please find a full output of this command as a github gist here: https://gist.github.com/mehstg/0b8016f5398a8781c3ade8cf49c02680

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi - removing and re-deploying the kube-dns would cause the same issues?

Comment: Hi. Yes. Have tried removing and redeploying. Same issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed your cluster with kubeadm you should add a pod network after installing.

If you choose flannel as your pod network, you should have this argument in your init command `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr 10.244.0.0/16`.

The flannel YAML file can be found in the [coreOS flannel repo](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml).

All you need to do if your cluster was initialized properly (read above), is to run `kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml`

Once this is up and running (it will create pods on every node), your kube-dns pod should come up.

If you need to reset your installation (for example to add the argument to `kubeadm init`), you can use `kubeadm reset` on all nodes.

Normally, you would run the init command on the master, then add a pod network, and then add your other nodes.

This is all described in more detail in the [Getting started guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/), step 3/4 regarding the pod network.

Comment: Thank you very much Morten. I shall run through this tomorrow and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Hi Morten. I looked through the getting started guide today, however this is different to the one I followed on the CoreOS website. I used this - https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-on-generic-platforms.html and used the build scripts to initiate the boxes. I had also set flannel up on the CoreOS boxes so not sure if I still need the pod network.

Comment: I am facing exactly same issue mentioned in the question but with weave-net.
Will same solution work for my issue? As far as I know, we specify pod-network-cidr only in case of flannel

Answer (score 0):

as your gist says your pod network seems to be broken. You are using some custom podnetwork with 10.10.10.X. You should communicate this IPs to all components.

Please check, there is no collision with other existing nets.

I recommend you to setup with Calico, as this was the solution for me to bring up CoreOS k8s up working

Comment: Hi David. I must have missed that in the log output. Where in my gist does it show that the networking is broken (For future reference when I am debugging). Morten has replied below and I will try his suggestion, I just appear to be looking through the log line that says the network is broken.

Answer (score 0):

After followed the steps in the official kubeadm doc with flannel networking, I run into a similar issue

http://janetkuo.github.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/

It appears as networking pods get stuck in error states:

kube-dns-xxxxxxxx-xxxvn  (rpc error)

kube-flannel-ds-xxxxx      (CrashLoopBackOff)

kube-flannel-ds-xxxxx      (CrashLoopBackOff)

kube-flannel-ds-xxxxx      (CrashLoopBackOff)

In my case it is related to rbac permission errors and is resolved by running

kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel-rbac.yml

Afterwards, all kube-system pods went into running states.  The upstream issue is discussed on github https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44029